# Database query problem

Tags: mysql, qt

I have a database it has too many records. I want to show them on screen. But I dont want to
load all of them on ram. I try to show them with a scrollbar. When scrollbar clik next 40 records comes. But I cant understand down or up. I use qt and c++. I show them in QTableWidget. Do you have any ideas. thanks a lot.

Comment: I do not think it deserves a down-vote. He's just asking for ideas -- not code.

Comment: Still, the question is very vaguely asked, i.e. where exactly in the process of pagination john wants more information about.

Answer (score 2):

In a word: pagination.  Do a Google or [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605368/how-to-paginate-a-qplaintextedit) search; you aren't the first to face this issue.