# How to access QTextDocument pages

Tags: python, qt, qt4, qtextedit, qtextdocument

I am trying to build an application that would display rich text documents in paginated fashion - more or less like MS Word does. For now, I would like to have only one page displayed at a time.

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605368/how-to-paginate-a-qplaintextedit) I have learned that I need to represent the document by [QTextDocument](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextdocument.html). While the author of the question focuses more on the *view* representation, I would like to learn about accessing document *data* in paginated fashion. I can see that the class has methods such as `setPageSize()` and `pageCount()`. Calling `setPageSize()` seems to update `pageCount()` accordingly.

The problem is I do not know how to access the contents of a chosen page to have it displayed in QtextEdit.

(I am accessing Qt from Python by means of PySide library)

Answer (score 2):

The `QTextEdit` is a text editor and does not really have a concept of pages, instead it's focused around paragraphs.

You could create your own paginated view that would respect the page sizes, but Qt already provide one for you. Have a look at the `QPrintPreviewWidget` or `QPrintPreviewDialog`. They are easy to use with `QTextEdit`.

Subclass `QTextEdit` and implement the following functions (the `preview` function is a Qt slot). The `printPreview` function will show a paginated view in a dialog with the contents of your `QTextEdit`.

```
void MyTextEdit::printPreview(QPrinter *printer)
{
    QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
    QPrintPreviewDialog preview(&printer, this);
    connect(&preview, SIGNAL(paintRequested(QPrinter*)), SLOT(preview(QPrinter*)));
    preview.exec();
}

void MyTextEdit::preview(QPrinter *printer)
{
     print(printer);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am going to try to translate your solution to Python and see how it works.